# Is there a way to specify a different function when passed a lvalue and another when not?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

Apologies in advance if I am not using the right terminology.

I'd like to have 2 functions *with the same name*, one that is called when the value is an lvalue and one when it is not.  Example:

```
typedef void (*fn_t)();
void fn() { }

fn_t pFn = fn;

fn_t* distinguish(fn_t pFn)
{
  return pFn;
}

// NOTE: Will not work
fn_t*& distinguish(fn_t& pFn)
{
  return pFn;
}

fn_t*& distinguish1(fn_t& pFn)
{
  return pFn;
}

int main()
{
  // call the one that takes a parameter from which I cannot get the address of the function pointer
  distinguish(fn);

  fn_t pFn = fn;
// call the one that takes a parameter from which I can get the address of the function pointer
  distinguish(pFn);
  distinguish1(pFn); // this will work
  distinguish1(fn); // this will not work
  return 0;
}
```

Is this possible?  Maybe I can use SFINAE?

## What I am attempting to do:

I'm using detours and I find that the cast that they use very ugly, so I've written a couple of template functions to do the casting for me.

```
// Cast a function pointer to a void *
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void* fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE(WINAPI * pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
    return (void*)pOriginalFunction;
}

// Cast a function pointer that is referencable to a void *&
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void*& fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef(RET_TYPE(WINAPI*& pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
    return (void*&)pOriginalFunction;
}
```

This allows me to do the following call:

```
BOOL (WINAPI *pDestroyIcon)(HICON) = DestroyIcon;
DetourAttach(&fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef(pDestroyIcon), fnPtrToVoidPtr(DestroyIcon));
```

However, I was wondering if I could consolidate the two function names `fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef` and `fnPtrToVoidPtr` into one name.

Doing the following doesn't work as it can't deduce the template arguments:

```
// Cast a function pointer to a void *
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void* fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE(WINAPI * & pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
    return (void*)pOriginalFunction;
}

// Cast a function pointer that is referencable to a void *&
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void*& fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE(WINAPI * && pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
    return (void*&)pOriginalFunction;
}

BOOL (WINAPI *pDestroyIcon)(HICON) = DestroyIcon;
void* p1 = fnPtrToVoidPtr(DestroyIcon);
void** p2 = fnPtrToVoidPtr(pDestroyIcon);
```

But this causes the following error:

```
// error C2784: 'void *&`anonymous-namespace'::fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE (__stdcall *&&)(ARGs...))' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'
```

Using my original functions, this works fine:

```
    BOOL (WINAPI *pDestroyIcon)(HICON) = DestroyIcon;
    void* p1 = fnPtrToVoidPtr(DestroyIcon);
    void** p2 = &fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef(pDestroyIcon);
```

Comment: I find the question (and the goal?) confusing: You cannot take the address of a *type*. You can only take the address of a *value*.

Comment: An lvalue, specifically.

Comment: I guess you mean *dereferencable* (i.e. a type you can apply the `*` operator to), not "referencable" (which doesn't really mean anything)?

Comment: @MikeSeymour, no, I mean a value from which I can get a reference to, not that I can dereference.

Comment: @Adrian: In that case, the question makes no sense. You can get a reference to any value. Please clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That is why I have an example.  I'm not sure how to better explain it.

Comment: @Adrian: But your example makes no sense either. You can take a reference to both `fn` and `pFn` (and any other value of any type). You can distinguish between a function and a function-pointer in various ways, but not according to whether you can take a reference.

Comment: Your example has several errors, most importantly the use of `fn_t*` when you want just `fn_t` (`fn_t` is already a pointer). After fixing those errors, you're right, it shows the call as ambiguous. But simply overloading to take `fn_t&&` and `fn_t&` is enough to get rid of that problem. Is that what you're after, or is there more to it?

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Ok, let me update the question more.

Comment: I suppose another thing that needs clarification is whether you really mean "taking the address" (i.e. applying `std::addressof`), or "form an address-of expression" like `&x`. The latter is more complex.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I think the former should be sufficient.

Comment: Now you say you want to distinguish whether the argument is an _lvalue_, in which case you'd overload for _lvalue_ and _rvalue_ references, `&` and `&&`. But all the examples call the function with an _lvalue_, so it's still not at all clear whether that's what you actually want. Please give a coherent description, with matching examples, of exactly which criteria you want to distinguish.

Comment: That code--isn't `std::forward` relevant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Cast a function pointer to a void *
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void* fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE(WINAPI *&& pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...)) {
  return (void*)pOriginalFunction;
}
// Cast a function pointer that is referencable to a void *&
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void*& fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE(WINAPI*& pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...)) {
  return (void*&)pOriginalFunction;
}
```

is I think what you want.  rvalue gets `&&` lvalue `&` and no ambiguity detected.

Now the above has the downside that the `&&` case won't deduce the signature properly.  I could work out how, or I could use brute force to avoid the problem.  We move the two into a `details` namespace, we add in a tag type to dispatch between the two, we remove the `&&`, and then we add a dispatching function as follows:

```
namespace details {
  template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
  void* fnPtrToVoidPtr(std::true_type, RET_TYPE(WINAPI * pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...)) {
    return (void*)pOriginalFunction;
  }
  // Cast a function pointer that is referencable to a void *&
  template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
  void*& fnPtrToVoidPtr(std::false_type, RET_TYPE(WINAPI*& pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...)) {
    return (void*&)pOriginalFunction;
  }

}
template<class T>
auto fnPtrToVoidPtr(T&& t)
-> decltype(
  details::fnPtrToVoidPtr(
    std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>{}, std::forward<T>(t)
  )
) {
  return
  details::fnPtrToVoidPtr(
    std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>{}, std::forward<T>(t)
  );
}
```

meh, what a mess.

For the above to work, you need to pass in `&foo` if `foo` is a function name.  If you pass in just `foo`, it will fail to compile.  You could write an adapter that maps `R(&)(Args...)` to `R(*)(Args...)` if you want, or otherwise fix that quirk.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73f3f99c61e06b87)

Comment: Maybe no ambiguity, but it can no longer do template deduction. :( Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @Adrian added some code in an attempt to get around your deduction issue.

Comment: Oh my! Wow! That's a bit crazy! :D But I guess it works. o.O Are unnamed parameters not actually passed and just used for call differentiation? I was never clear on that point in C++.

Comment: Oh, but wait, won't `std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>` always give a `true_type` since you're explicitly stating the `&&` after the `T`?

Comment: No, this doesn't work. `error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type fnPtrToVoidPtr(T &&)'`

Comment: @adri on phone, have limited code editing/testing ability.  plus watching 2yo.  May fix later: can you set up an ideone that generates your error?

Comment: Np. I use wandbox. Ideone has really gone downhill. You can find the sample [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LCJr7rGDmB8rAZgL).

Comment: NOTE: getting it to run on another compiler is well and fine, but if it doesn't work in the VC++ compiler, it is useless to me.  Please test [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/).  Unfortunately, this doesn't allow you to save the code.  M$ is stingy like that. :/

Comment: @Adrian I found that I got issues if I passed in raw `foo` function names, but `&foo` worked fine.  I tested it on that link, and it compiled and ran.  A problem is that `foo` is an lvalue reference to a function (hence the ability to take its address!), but `&foo` is an rvalue pointer to a function.

Comment: I found a solution to the type deduction by asking another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590069/template-deduction-not-working-for-function-pointer-reference).  Turns out your way to get the deduction to work is unnecessary.  But thanks for your help.  Your original answer is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem here is that you're messing up the number of indirections on the usage of your typedef. I have resolved the issue in [this associated sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f53e2189dbc3b33c).

In short, the reason why it doesn't work is because you took a `fn_t*&`. The value `pFn` is only a `fn_t`, not a `fn_t*`. This is why the reference cannot refer to it. Since `fn_t` already contains the pointer part, you do not need to add additional pointers to it.

Comment: ... so what's the problem remaining? Your sample has no problems left.

Comment: The problem is that the compiler can not do template deduction on the type && and & it seems.  I guess I'll start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** You don't need `std::forward` here, but it's just for show to illustrate a more "transparent" view of values passing through functions.

Use & and && when needed, where & = lvalue and && = rvalue.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81539ac10b8be5a1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int& forward(int& i)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue: ";
    return std::forward<int&>(i);   
}

int&& forward(int&& i)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue: ";
    return std::forward<int&&>(i);    
}

int*&& forward(int*&& ptr_i)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue ptr: ";
    return std::forward<int*&&>(ptr_i);   
}

int*& forward(int*& ptr_i)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue ptr: ";
    return std::forward<int*&>(ptr_i);   
}

const int* forward(const int* const  ptr_to_const)
{
    std::cout << "const ptr to lvalue: ";
    return std::forward<const int* const>(ptr_to_const);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;

    const int j = 13;

    int* ptr_i = &i;

    const int * const  const_ptr_const_i = &j;

    int * const const_ptr_i = &i;


    std::cout << forward(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << forward(i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << forward(ptr_i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << forward(&i) << std::endl;

    //These two are almost the same by nature; note the variables they point to are different.
    std::cout << forward(const_ptr_const_i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << forward(const_ptr_i) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Cannot have a const pointer to a const rvalue because you can't really have a const pointer to a temporary/disappearing/ephermal rvalue." << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `std::forward` does not really make sense outside of templates.

Comment: The example is the same if you try to return just an `int` without `std::forward`.