# Template deduction not working for function pointer reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-argument-deduction

I'm using detours and I find that the cast that they use very ugly, so I've written a couple of template functions to do the casting for me.

```
// Cast a function pointer to a void *
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void* fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE(WINAPI * pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
    return (void*)pOriginalFunction;
}

// Cast a function pointer that is referencable to a void *&
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void*& fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef(RET_TYPE(WINAPI*& pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
    return (void*&)pOriginalFunction;
}
```

This allows me to do the following call:

```
BOOL (WINAPI *pDestroyIcon)(HICON) = DestroyIcon;
DetourAttach(&fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef(pDestroyIcon), fnPtrToVoidPtr(DestroyIcon));
```

However, I was wondering if I could consolidate the two function names `fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef` and `fnPtrToVoidPtr` into one name.

Doing the following doesn't work as it can't deduce the template arguments:

```
// Cast a function pointer to a void *
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void* fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE(WINAPI * & pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
    return (void*)pOriginalFunction;
}

// Cast a function pointer that is referencable to a void *&
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void*& fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE(WINAPI * && pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
    return (void*&)pOriginalFunction;
}

BOOL (WINAPI *pDestroyIcon)(HICON) = DestroyIcon;
void* p1 = fnPtrToVoidPtr(DestroyIcon);
void** p2 = &fnPtrToVoidPtr(pDestroyIcon);
```

causing the following error:

```
// error C2784: 'void *&fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE (__stdcall *&&)(ARGs...))' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'
```

Using my original functions, this works fine:

```
    BOOL (WINAPI *pDestroyIcon)(HICON) = DestroyIcon;
    void* p1 = fnPtrToVoidPtr(DestroyIcon);
    void** p2 = &fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef(pDestroyIcon);
```

However, if I change `fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef` to this:

```
// Cast a function pointer that is referencable to a void *&
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void*& fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef(RET_TYPE(WINAPI*&& pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
    return (void*&)pOriginalFunction;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error C2664: 'void *&fnPtrRefToVoidPtrRef<BOOL,HICON>(RET_TYPE (__stdcall *&&)(HICON))' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'BOOL (__stdcall *)(HICON)' to 'BOOL (__stdcall *&&)(HICON)'
```

Which seems to be why it can't do template deduction, it doesn't recognize it to be the same (or convertible?) type.  Is there a way to get C++ to properly deduce the function pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. Let's fix them in order.

First, the bodies and return types of the two `fnPtrToVoidPtr` overloads have to be switched. What you want is to convert lvalues of function pointer type to lvalues of type `void*`, through the `(void*&)` cast, so this cast should go in the body of the function taking a `* &` - this is the parameter type that will bind to modifiable lvalues, the other one, `* &&` will bind to rvalues. Conversely, the `(void*)` cast has to go into the function taking a `* &&`. Obviously, the return types need to be changed accordingly.

Now, the reason for the deduction failure: when making a call like `fnPtrToVoidPtr(DestroyIcon)` in your original version, you're relying on the function-to-pointer conversion. This conversion doesn't happen if the parameter (destination) is a reference.

So, in your second version, where both overloads take references, the parameters are references to pointers, but the argument is a function identifier; template arguments for the former cannot be deduced from the latter, so deduction fails. The simplest fix for this one is to explicitly provide a function pointer for the call, like this: `fnPtrToVoidPtr(&DestroyIcon)`.

`&DestroyIcon` is an rvalue, so the `* &&` parameter will bind to it, `* &` won't, exactly what we want.

With these two fixes, a compilable version of your code becomes:

```
#include "windows.h"

// Cast a function pointer to a void *
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void* fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE(WINAPI * && pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
   return (void*)pOriginalFunction;
}

// Cast a function pointer that is referencable to a void *&
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void*& fnPtrToVoidPtr(RET_TYPE(WINAPI * & pOriginalFunction)(ARGs...))
{
   return (void*&)pOriginalFunction;
}

BOOL(WINAPI *pDestroyIcon)(HICON) = DestroyIcon;

int main()
{
   void* p1 = fnPtrToVoidPtr(&DestroyIcon);
   void** p2 = &fnPtrToVoidPtr(pDestroyIcon);
}
```

If you don't like having to use the `&` operator in front of function names, you can also change the overload taking a `* &&` to take a `&` - an lvalue reference to a function. Now, that version can be called as `fnPtrToVoidPtr(DestroyIcon)`. A `&&` (rvalue reference to function) will work too, since rvalue references to functions bind to function lvalues as well (all identifier expressions designating functions are lvalues).

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days!  Of course template deduction doesn't work if it has to coerce the type.  This makes so much sense.  THANK YOU!